# In the triangle $ABC$ $M$ is the middle of the side $AB$ and $CE$ is an altitude. Find the angles of triangle $ABC$ if...

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the triangle $ABC$ $M$ is the middle of the side $AB$ and $CE$ is an altitude. Find the angles of triangle $ABC$ if $CM$ and $CE$ split the angle $ACB$ in three equal parts.

I've figured out that triangles $CME$ and $CBE$ are congruent, but I'm not sure what to do exactly to be able to find out the exact angles of triangle $ABC$. ($ACB=3x,ABC=90-x,CAB=270-2x$).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide an accurate figure: If CE is an altitude, one should find a right angle in $E$ !

Comment: A similar issue [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3279894)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about $\triangle CEM$ and $\triangle CEB$, then you know about what kind of triangle is $\triangle CEA$. You might also know in what ratio $E$ splits $MB$ and as a consequence in what ratio $M$ splits $AE$.
Now it's probably the time for [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), since $CM$ is a bisector of $\triangle CEA$. And in no time we received all the information we need to get the $\angle A$, and then other two angles.